# When do I use correlation and entropy for Feature Selection?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, feature-selection, data-transformation, descriptive-statistics

I am wondering when to use correlation and entropy to select features from the dataset. I understand correlation and it is used to see how correlated two variables are and it is only used between two real type variables?

But I don't really see when to use entropy to selected features. What kind of variables can I use entropy for selecting features? Is entropy used only for two categorical variables?